Homogeneous notation for quadratic polynomials
I was reading the lecture "$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$" by Serre and stumbled upon the claim

To see them [the other symmetries of the discriminant of $ax^2 + bx + c$], it is better to use a homogeneous notation, and to write our polynomials as $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.

Then he introduces the transformations $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
My questions are:

Why do we need this "homogeneous notation"?
Is $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ the group of all discriminant-preserving transformations?

